# Равное расстояние, между блоками при работе с flex css в много строчном режиме

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Задача стоит в следующем. Я использую `flex` для расстановки блоков. Однако, когда блоков много, их приходится переносить на следующую строку. Но блоки распределяются равномерно, четко по линии.

Как сделать так, как я привел в скриншоте?

Проблема не в том, что бы их так расположить, а что бы они автоматически выстраивались, в зависимости от высоты блоков внутри блока с flex.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Это называется `Masonry layout`. Может помогут [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645254/227016) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/552956/227016) вопросы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать css-колонки:

```css
body {
  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: silver;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula dui quis nibh congue sollicitudin. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut ultricies aliquam tortor sit amet fermentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis in facilisis massa, sit amet convallis dolor. Sed scelerisque ipsum quis felis cursus iaculis eu at elit. Donec ornare dapibus fringilla.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula dui quis nibh congue sollicitudin. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula dui quis nibh congue sollicitudin. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut ultricies aliquam tortor sit amet fermentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis in facilisis massa, sit amet convallis dolor..</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula dui quis nibh congue sollicitudin. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut ultricies aliquam tortor sit amet fermentum.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vehicula dui quis nibh congue sollicitudin. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
```

PS: [`user:178988 page-break-inside`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+page-break-inside)

Comment: у меня эти блоки обвернуты блоком с таким вот кодом display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 100%;   Хотелось бы использовать flex. Какое то значение видимо мешает.

Comment: @Денис, всё перечисленное. Оставь `display: block` :)

Comment: Они нужны что б распределить блоки равномерно по длине страницы, а так же что б их переносить. justify-content: space-between; Очень нужен мне.

Comment: @Денис, если ни колонки, ни флекс с колонками не подходят, придётся использовать скрипты для расстановки блоков.

Comment: Чуть выше дали ссылки на темы, там было упоминание и flex методов. Но почему то не срабатывает. Скрипты не хочу использовать.

Comment: @Денис, по первой ссылке: принятый ответ с колонками как у меня, второй - со скриптом либо _вертикальным_ флексом; по второй ссылке в одном ответе равная высота элементов, в другом опять колонки, а в ответе с -3 вообще непонятно что. Так что из css-вариантов только вертикальный флекс и колонки. главная разница между ними в том, что флексу будет нужна высота контейнера, иначе он не станет переноситься, а колонки постараются распределиться на всю ширину при автоматической высоте. Возможно, флекс более удобен в управлении, но если у контейнера нет высоты, то не прокатит точно.

Comment: Я уже понял. Спасибо.